# Null Pointer Exception: null error

Tags: java, hashset

I have this Hash Set code and when I try to run my compile method on it I get the Null Pointer Exception: null  error on it. Here is the code:

```
private void initKeywords() {
        keywords = new HashSet<String>();
        keywords.add("final");
        keywords.add("int");
        keywords.add("while");
        keywords.add("if");
        keywords.add("else");
        keywords.add("print");     
    }

    private boolean isIdent(String t) {
        if (keywords.contains(t)) {  ***//This is the line I get the Error***
            return false;
        }
        else if (t != null && t.length() > 0 && Character.isLetter(t.charAt(0))) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The other lines that goes along with this error is:

```
public void compileProgram() {        
        System.out.println("compiling " + filename);
        while (theToken != null) {
            if (equals(theToken, "int") || equals(theToken, "final")) {
                compileDeclaration(true);
            } else {
                compileFunction(); //This line is giving an error with the above error
            }
        }
        cs.emit(Machine.HALT);
        isCompiled = true;
    }



private void compileFunction() {
        String fname = theToken;
        int entryPoint = cs.getPos();  
        if (equals(fname, "main")) {
            cs.setEntry(entryPoint);
        } 
        if (isIdent(theToken)) theToken = t.token(); ***//This line is giving an error***
        else t.error("expecting identifier, got " + theToken);

        symTable.allocProc(fname,entryPoint);


       accept("(");
        compileParamList();
        accept(")");
        compileCompound(true);
        if (equals(fname, "main")) cs.emit(Machine.HALT);
        else cs.emit(Machine.RET);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `keywords` or `t` is null. Using either a debugger or print statements it should be pretty simple to determine. If `keywords` is null, I'd assume that `initKeywords()` has not been called yet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're running `initKeywords()` before `isIdent()`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `initKeywords` from the constructor of this object.

Answer (score 0):

I personally try to stay away from init methods.  As previously mentioned, a constructor serves as an initializer, and so does the static block:

```
private final static Set<String> KEYWORDS = new HashSet<String>();
static {
        keywords.add("final");
        keywords.add("int");
        keywords.add("while");
        keywords.add("if");
        keywords.add("else");
        keywords.add("print");
}
```